# Sticking to One Action during Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm currently working on a reinforcement learning project and encountering an issue where the agent consistently sticks to one particular action as training progresses. Initially, the agent's actions are quite random, which is expected. However, after several training episodes, it starts to heavily favor one specific action, regardless of the state or situation. Also, favoring(?) action is quite random. Sometimes action 0, sometimes action 1, etc.

What can cause this .. favorite action syndrome?

I'm using Actor-Critic algorithm and

Network structures are..

```
for x1,  for x1
[Conv2d] [Conv2d] 
[Conv1d] [Conv1d]
[Conv1d] [Conv1d]
[merged & linear]
[linear .. ]
[linear]
[lin..]
[output]
```

using epsilon greedy exploration with epsilon=1, decay=0.97754, min_epsilon=0.01

I have tried adjusting the exploration rate and modifying the reward function, but the issue persists.

I tried multiply some ..balance stress index to loss tensor and even if the balance stress index go to rocket-high, some random action just skyrocketing. Has anyone experienced similar issues in reinforcement learning scenarios? Any suggestions on how to encourage the agent to explore more diverse actions would be greatly appreciated.